# Is it possible to use variables in append classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder if it is possible to have a variable inside a class inside an append?

**I want this:**

```
var VARIABLE = test123
 $('.multiple_' + index2 +'_variants .datacursusul').append('<li class="VARIABLE"><span class="dates">' + allmonths + '</span>' + oldvartitle + '</li>');
```

**So that the outcome is:**

```
<li class="test123"><span class="dates">ETC</span></li>
```

Comment: Really, you didn't try this with a variable that is actually a valid string ?

Comment: I had tried something, but I probably messed it up, so I wasn't sure anymore if it was even possible.. #stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `+` for string concatenation in javascript:

```
var VARIABLE = "test123";
$('.multiple_' + index2 +'_variants .datacursusul').append('<li class="' + VARIABLE + '"><span class="dates">' + allmonths + '</span>' + oldvartitle + '</li>');
```

Comment: Wow, that was a pretty stupid question. haha, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
var VARIABLE = 'test123'
$('.multiple_' + index2 +'_variants .datacursusul').append('<li class="' + VARIABLE + '"><span class="dates">' + allmonths + '</span>' + oldvartitle + '</li>');
```

Comment: Wow, that was a pretty stupid question. haha, thanks :)